# Proof 4 color theorem, while number of vertices n < 12

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

The four color theorem is valid for all planar graph, but of course, nobody know an intuitive way to proof it now.

But how can we proof it when only number of vertices in the graph $n \lt 12$, I don't understand what is the special of the number $12$ in here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that a planar graph with all vertices of degree at least $5$ must have at least $12$ vertices. So if $n<12$ then there is always a vertex $v$ of degree at most $4$ that you can remove. Then there is a way to use a $4$-colouring of $G-v$ to construct a $4$-colouring of $G$.